# gdb user defined command throws error with argument

Tags: gdb

I am trying to write user defined command. I followed the `adder` example here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html

```
(gdb) define adder
Type commands for definition of "adder".
End with a line saying just "end".
>  set $i = 0
>  set $sum = 0
>  while $i < $argc
 >    eval "set $sum = $sum + $arg%d", $i
 >    set $i = $i + 1
 >  end
>  print $sum
>end
(gdb) adder 1 2 3
Argument to arithmetic operation not a number or boolean.
(gdb)
```

The syntax looks correct to me. Why am I getting error of `Argument to arithmetic operation not a number or boolean.`?

Comment: What version of GDB are you running?

Comment: gdb 7.12-6. Is it too old or is there alternative syntax?

Comment: You need at least 8.0, although at least one GNU/Linux  distribution ported the update to an earlier version. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021160/create-user-defined-gdb-command-to-print-all-arguments-values-to-log-file/45065592#45065592